# Load path ivy-* match any series number

Tags: emacs, package, versioning, load-path

I customize `load-path` for Ivy using a package suffix of -0.13.1:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.zeroemacs/elpa/ivy-0.13.1/")
```

However, when the ivy package upgraded to 0.14.1, I had to manually modify the `load-path` to

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.zeroemacs/elpa/ivy-0.14.1/")
```

Is it possible to replace it with something like `ivy-*` which match any series numbers?

Comment: Corrected second sexp, presuming you meant 14 for it, not 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version numbers come in many shapes and sizes. Rather than trying to deal with any and all version formats, the `latest-file-version` function below relies on comparing version strings accepted by the `version-to-list` function. The documentation for `version-to-list` includes this description of what it accepts:

> The version syntax is given by the following EBNF:
>
> VERSION ::= NUMBER ( SEPARATOR NUMBER )*.
>
> NUMBER ::= (0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)+.
>
> SEPARATOR ::= ‘version-separator’ (which see)
> | ‘version-regexp-alist’ (which see).
>
> The NUMBER part is optional if SEPARATOR is a match for an element in ‘version-regexp-alist’.

You can use the `latest-file-version` function in your `load-path` setting like this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (latest-file-version "~/.zeroemacs/elpa" "ivy"))
```

The first argument is the directory to check, and the second argument is the prefix of the versioned filenames or directory names to check.

```
(defun latest-file-version (dir prefix)
  "Get the latest version of files in DIR starting with PREFIX.
Only filenames in DIR with the form PREFIX-version are
considered, where the version portion of the filename must have
valid version syntax as specified for `version-to-list'. Raise an
error if no filenames in DIR start with PREFIX or if no valid
matching versioned filenames are found."
  (let* ((vsn-regex (concat "^" prefix "-\\(.+\\)$"))
         (vsn-entries
          (seq-reduce
           #'(lambda (acc s)
               (if (string-match vsn-regex s)
                   (let* ((m (match-string 1 s))
                          (vsn (condition-case nil
                                   (version-to-list m)
                                 (error nil))))
                     (if vsn
                         (cons (cons m s) acc)
                       acc))
                 acc)) 
           (directory-files dir nil nil t) nil)))
    (if vsn-entries
        (concat (file-name-as-directory dir)
          (cdar (sort vsn-entries
                      #'(lambda (v1 v2)
                          (version<= (car v2) (car v1))))))
      (error "No valid versioned filenames found in %s with prefix \"%s-\""
             dir prefix))))
```

Tested with emacs 27.1.